# Magento hierarchy of override

Tags: magento, controller, overriding, hierarchy

does anyone knows what is the hierarchy of overriding e.g. controllers?

For example:
I want to override the AccountController in 'local'.
But there is a community plugin that also overrides this controller.
Maybe there is also another local module that overrides the Core AccountController.

What can I do to influence Magento to use my custom AccountController?

Answer (score 2):

All the three code pools ie. local, community & core having the following priority in magento

```
1. local
2. community
3. core
```

So Magento search the files in local first then community & in last core code pool.

Hope this help you.

Comment: Thank you. Ok that order is helpful.  
And what happens when there are two or more controllers in local that override the same core controller?

Comment: I think you are confused in overriding and extending.....core controller can't be override more than once in a code pool....

Custom module ever extends the core controller files....

Answer (score 1):

You need to override community module AccountController with your controller.
 also add code in config.xml

```
<config> 
  <modules> 
        <Extenstion_Communitymodule> 
          <depends><Yourmodule_Modulename/></depends>
         </Extenstion_Communitymodule>
   </modules>
    </config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento has three code pools.

`core` `community` and `local`.

Code pools are located inside the folder ‘app/code’ which contain all magento modules.

*core*:This are core modules of magento,Dont try to edit this folder.

*community*:This contains third party modules.

*local*:This is the folder created by you, you can edit this any time.

If you want to override any file or controller do it in local folder.

Local has the Highest priority.
Then community folder 
and then core has least priority 
But if you change core folder it will affect and loose all your changes when you upgrade magento.